# Sacks Minhag Anglia Machzorim

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

If you look in the Koren catalogue or Amazon.co.uk, you will notice that there is a British edition of the Koren Sacks machzorim.

I have been wondering about these editions, in my pursuit of whether I should get them or not, as an alternative to searching for reprints of the Rödelheim editions.

1. Do they include the traditional order of Birchot HaShachar or the modern Israeli one?
2. Do they include the yotzerot in their proper placement, or are they located in the back, as with the version of the Sacks available in the US?
3. Does the Yom Kippur version include the Selichot for the rest of the day, or just the ones for Ma'ariv and Ne'ilah?
4. Which version of B'fi Yisharim do they use in Shochen ad?
5. For those who have experience with the Rödelheim editions, how similar are they?

Comment: I cannot answer your question. But interestingly the Yomim Noraim Machzorim have the word לחיים 
(as in for example זכרנו לחיים) vowelized with a patach under the lamed.)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, which y"n machzorim?

Comment: Koren Sacks Minhag Anglia Machzorim

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, why don't you answer the parts you can. I just through the last one in on the off-chance that someone would know.

Comment: Sorry - only saw it once and looked for the thing that interested me.

Comment: I'm in the UK. I'd have to look in Torah Treasures in Golders Green Road for you.

What is the modern Israel order for Birchot HaShachar? What Slichot are there on Yom Kippur during the day? 4. Do you mean Yamim Naroim or other festivals?

Comment: @CashCow, in order of what you asked: Modern Israeli b"sh puts asher yotzar, elokai neshama, and birchot hatorah before yigdal and a"o. Think Artscroll vs. Koren. In the Adler and Rödelheim machzorim, following the western Ashkenazi minhag, selichot were recited at every service on Y"K. I do mean Y"N, as only one sh"r machzor is presently available (and is not that useful, because I'd still need to tip in a good amount of my own notes)

Comment: Artscroll has a strange order. You put tefillin on before washing hands? They'll get wet. I don't get the order of artscroll.. I wash hands first, then put tefillin on..

Comment: @CashCow, nearly every siddur I've seen does that. I put on tallit and tefillin right before Baruch She'amar.